# What name to use in Html.BeginForm for async controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous

Let's say I have an async controller like that below ~

```
public class HomeController : AsyncController
{
    public void LoadAync(DumpModel model) {  

    }

    public ActionResult LoadCompleted(string a) {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

How can I invoke this method from View?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Load", "Home"))
```

I tried using this one but it doesn't work. I can invoke only when I change "Load" to "LoadAsync" in View. But "LoadCompleted" will never be called.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spelling of Async in wrong and MVC is convention based.

```
public void LoadAsync(DumpModel model) {  

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. It should be `LoadAsync` and not `LoadAync`.

Comment: Thanks! you both are right but I can mark only one as answer. Thanks a lot!